# Create PO from Requisition but Generate to Sales Order

Tags: adempiere

I made Requisition in Adempiere and planned to make Purchase Order automatically by using "Create PO from Requisition". It was successfully created but it turns out that it generates to Sales Order instead of Purchase Order.

Why is it and How can I solve it?

Any suggestion will be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

What version of Adempiere?
Do you have any customizations?
Does it work in the test GardenWorld demo customer?
I tested the process in the 380LTS version and it corrected created a Purchase Order.

*Note that both Sales Orders & Purchase Orders are stored in the same database table; the isSOTrx column differentiates them. Just in case you were not aware. ;)

Comment: I use Adempiere 3.8, Yes I had customizations, lots of customizations. It doesn't work when I tried with GardenAdmin, the Requisition document even won't be completed.

Comment: If the requisition document is not completed how can you convert it to an Order.. Sales or Purchase order?

Comment: If you create a Document (any document) in the GardenWorld demo today you must ensure that the financial periods have been created and open for now.  Maybe check if that is why you cannot COMPLETE the requisition.
Another thing to check is that the requisition value has not passed the point were approval is required.  If so then get the users supervisor to approve it... or for testing reduce value such that approval is not required.

Answer (score 0):

May be in creating the product in Material Management, you set the product as SOLD not PURCHASED. The checkbox mentioning sold must be deselected for purchased items